# Авторизация. Работа с внутренними моделями

Tags: php, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Столкнулся с непониманием. Имеется структура

```
/application
--controllers
----Home.php (extends Base)
----Base.php (extends Controller)
--models
----User.php
----Log.php
--views
--bootstrap.php
/system
--Auth.php
--Model.php
--Controller.php
```

Как принято загружаем в ***bootstrap.php*** основные параметры и классы. В нужном контроллере происходит аутентификация пользователя из ***Auth.php***. При этом надо например, залогировать что-то, изменить время входа пользователя... Вообщем получить доступ из ***Auth.php*** к моделям *User, Log*.
 При всем при этом ***Auth*** как бы системный (живет сам отдельно) и не должен знать о них. С другой стороны, он должен быть основой для базовой авторизации.
 Расширять его(добавление в *application/*) практически не вижу смысла, потому как для базовой авторизации не хватит данных о пользователе. То есть, если удалить все лишнее и оставить "чистую" систему авторизация может не выполниться. Выходит, что в системе ему делать нечего.

```
// Class в Auth.php
public function auth()
{
    // Есть  проблема передачи линка PDO
    // В контроллере есть для этого метод
    // А тут все в сыром виде
    $user_model = new User_Model($pdo);
    // Либо выполнять нижние  действия в методе
    $user = $user_model->authorize($id, $token);
    // Делаем действия, зависящие от других моделей
    $log = new Log_model($pdo);
    $task = new Task_Mdel($pdo);

    if ($user) {
        // Вошел
        $log->save('...');
        $task->update('...');
    } else {
        // Не вошел
        $log->save('...');
    }
```

Еще применяю DataMapper, поэтому ***Auth.php*** опять требуется знать о модели в ***User.php*** и о сущности пользователя. Долго все описывать, думаю понятна история.
Вопрос: Как желательно поступить в такой ситуации? Есть что почитать в кратком объеме?

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще, оператор new в бизнес-коде - плохая практика

Вариантов несколько, вот что приходит на ум:

**1.** Можно все делать через фабрику, сервис-контейнер или что-то подобное

К примеру, на Laravel, я бы сделал Интерфейс LoggingModelInterface, забайндил бы в ServiceProvider класс реализации модели лога
и в auth() сделал бы app(LoggingModelInterface::class)

Это бы уже уменьшило связанность auth и log, т.к. в сервис-провайдере мы можем в любой момент заменить реализацию интерфейса

**2.** Можно эмитить событие в auth(), а в подписчике на событие делать лог и все, что нужно

Что почитать:

почитай принципы SOLID (хотя, думаю, ты о них знаешь)

Вот [паттерны](https://refactoring.guru/ru)

И, имхо, лучший вариант - посмотреть код [хороших проектов на Laravel](https://github.com/chiraggude/awesome-laravel#codebases-for-reference)

Comment: на гуру давно заходил) спс. На счет new, это для примера, все сводится к тому, что Auth нужно быть контроллером, но при этом он является отдельным компонентом. Не понимаю как побороть

Comment: Для связи компонентов обычно фасады используют, но тогда Auth все равно будет знать о внешнем компоненте (через фасад). Если нужно, чтобы Auth вообще ничего не знал, тогда, на мой взгляд, события - единственный вариант